# How can I use a dictionary to iterate through my kivy properties and make changes to them?

Tags: python, button, kivy

For my kivy project I'm trying to create a dictionary with BooleanProperties in there. I want to use this for 6 buttons I wish to enable and disable a certain amount of them. I've tried doing that the way I would normally go and do it (Using only 3 properties for clarity):

```
class MainScreen(ScreenManager):
    disable_1 = BooleanProperty(True)
    disable_2 = BooleanProperty(True)
    disable_3 = BooleanProperty(True)
    buttonstates = []
```

my .kv code for the buttons look like this:

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_buttons_1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1"
            on_press: show_pictures_manager.get_children_of_screenmanager(1)
            disabled: root.disable_1
        Button:
            background_color: (0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1.1"
            disabled: root.disable_2
        Button:
            background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1.2"
            disabled: root.disable_3
```

The function I would like to use to iterate through them, and change their values is:

```
def change_button_states(self, amount_of_buttons_to_change):
    self.buttonstates = [self.disable_1, self.disable_2, self.disable_3]
    for no in range(3):
        self.buttonstates[1] = False
        print(self.buttonstates)
```

This code prints 3 times:

```
[True, False, True]
```

All well, however the (in this case) second button is not enabling itself. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

I noticed I created an instance of buttonstates but did not communicate with it in my function. I changed it to communicate with the self.buttonstates instance, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: what is `amount_of_buttons_to_change`?

Comment: The project I am building is about detecting items in pictures. So I want to detect items in pictures, and depending on how much items the app found activate buttons. In the end it would mean the buttons respond to what item they are representing. 

Edit: I realise you probably ask because I don't seem to use the variable. I wish to use it in the range() function as such:

`for no in range(amount_of_buttons_to_change):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in various ways.

The least amount of change in your code would simply use getattr, setattr.

```
for no in range(3):
    setattr(self, 'disable_%s' % no, False)
    print(getattr(self, 'disabled_%s' % no)
```

but you still need to create one property for each button, which is probably not flexible enough.

using a ListProperty instead and have each button lookup at its index to know if it has to be disabled could be better.

```
class MainScreen(ScreenManager):
    buttonstates = ListProperty([False, False, True])

<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_buttons_1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1"
            on_press: show_pictures_manager.get_children_of_screenmanager(1)
            disabled: root.buttonstates[0]
        Button:
            background_color: (0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1.1"
            disabled: root.buttonstates[1]
        Button:
            background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            text: "place 1.2"
            disabled: root.buttonstates[2]
```

then your function to change state is back to

```
def change_button_states(self, amount_of_buttons_to_change):
    for no in range(3):
        self.buttonstates[no] = False
        print(self.buttonstates)
```

you could also have a DictProperty, with an id for each button, and have the button lookup its id in the dict, so you can easily add/remove buttons and have some sane defaults.